# Php Simple File Manager?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-manager

Does anyone know the php/ajax file manager that has the colorful buttons (resembling bootstrap ui)? I am trying to find it but I completely forget what its called. The live online example page was just a white page with the basic upload buttons (upload, delete, etc.) It also allowed multiple file uploads, and had a js progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is what most third party free file uploaders are now a days. You might as well be asking what mountain is somewhere that resembles rock...

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple but powerful file manager exactly as you described. Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/ashishdoneriya/vuedisk)